# SharePoint search on local drive

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, search-scope

In my company we have a fileserver where all the documents are located, and we can access it using [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer).

`\\intern.contoso.com\data` or drive L.

Since we save a lot of data here, it would be great if we could configure the SharePoint search engine to search through this content directly, without copying everything into our SharePoint documents. Is there a way we could achieve this?

I am using SharePoint 2013 and [Windows Server 2012 R2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012#Windows_Server_2012_R2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Crawling file shares is very easy to set up, and permissions are accounted for - so there is no risk that users find information they don't have access to.

In *Central Admin Search Service Application*, add a new *Content Source*. Specify your file server and set up a schedule. Do a full crawl and you're up and running in no time.

[image]

Comment: @fmeci Great! Come back for more questions if you need more help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sure :)

You Could create a **Content Source** of **FILE SHARE** type.

And give **\intern.contoso.com\data** as Network Path.

Full Crawl the Content Source and your results will be ready.

Please check the snapshot for FileShare Content Source option.
[image: File Share]